# Hi ive got a sqlite database and im trying to find a way to try and output a user into some entry boxes and im getting an error

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter, search, save

This is the error im getting
Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 0 supplied.

This is the code which isnt working

```
enw=enwinput.get()
conn=sqlite3.connect("login.db")
c=conn.cursor()
c.execute("SELECT enw, * FROM manylion WHERE enw=?", (enw))
sql = "SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE id=?"
```

Comment: Did you checked if anything is coming in this - enw=enwinput.get()

Comment: yes i have an entry box for that which i can input into

Comment: Try this, if it works for you - https://techoverflow.net/2019/10/14/how-to-fix-sqlite3-python-incorrect-number-of-bindings-supplied-the-current-statement-uses-1-supplied/   Basically enclose enw in [] - square bracket

Comment: Change `(enw)` to `(enw,)` to make it a tuple.

Comment: `enw` will be included in `*`, you don't need to specify it explicitly.

Comment: still getting the same error

Comment: Update your question with what you have tried based on the comments and show the full error traceback.  *"still getting the same error"* doesn't help us to solve the issue.